# ethereum rpc , send transaction

Tags: ethereum

How to send a transaction using RPC on ethereum.?

On documentation I see this:

```
params: [{
  "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
  "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
  "gas": "0x76c0", // 30400,
  "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
  "value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
  "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
}]
```

Where do I find this:

> data": "0xd46e.......72445675

Is there any simple library that I can input only amount and the address of transaction?

Answer (score 1):

[Web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) is the de-facto library for interacting with ethereum which you can use. There's great [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) on how to send transactions.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject [, callback])
```

The data field is either a byte string containing the associated data of the message, or in the case of a contract-creation transaction, the initialization code. Data of messages are encoded methods and their argument values. You can use the library [ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi) to encode and decode data fields.

Answer (score 0):

1. "data" parameter is not for you, if you just want to make a simple transaction.
2. To make simple transaction, you can simply ignore all parameters except "from", "to" and "value" and call the method in this way:

   `params: [{
     "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
     "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
     "value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
   }]`
3. You asked for simple library with just amount and address. It seems by address you mean "to" address. Unlike bitcoin rpc, which simply uses all addresses belongs to wallet as source of transaction, you should define exact "from" address with ethereum rpc.

Comment: wouldn't they need to sign this with their private key somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a couple of wrappers around [Web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) for [NodeJS](https://github.com/ledfusion/eth-tx) and [Web browsers](https://github.com/ledfusion/web3-wrap).

The latter one helps abstracting connections and contract development.

```
const { connect, useConnection, sendTransaction } = require("web3-wrap");

try {
    if(window.web3){
        await useConnection(window.web3);
    }
    else {
        await connect();
    }

    const receipt = await sendTransaction({
        to: "0x1234...",
        value: 10 // amount to transfer, in wei
    });
    console.log("Receipt:", receipt);
}
catch(err){
    console.error(err && err.message || err);
}
```

Hope it heps